# Реакция DataGridView на BindingSource.MoveNext и др. подобные методы в другом потоке

Tags: winforms, многопоточность, datagridview, vb.net, bindingsource

Имеется BindingSource и DataGridView, причем DataGridView.DataSource = BindingSource.
Когда вызывается метод BindingSource.MoveNext и другие подобные методы в потоке ГУИ, в DataGridView визуально выделяется соотв. строка, т. е. все работает так, как надо.
Если метод BindingSource.MoveNext запускать в другом потоке в помощью BackgroundWorker, то DataGridView никак не реагирует на  изменение позиции BindingSource.
Смог добиться обновления DataGridView вызовом метода BindingSource.ResetBindings(False), но это неудобно.
Есть ли другой способ? Заранее спасибо.
[Пример](https://yadi.sk/d/7GOyB3RZc-onvQ)

Comment: Укажите язык программирования. C#? И GUI-фреймворк. WinForms?

Comment: Спасибо, я уже разобрался. Вместо стандартного BindingSource нужно использовать следующий:а

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, я уже разобрался. Вместо стандартного BindingSource нужно использовать следующий:

```html
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
''' <summary>
''' Инкапсулирует источник данных (некоторые события вызываются в потоке ГУИ).
''' </summary>
Public Class SyncBindingSource
  Inherits BindingSource
  Private syncContext As SynchronizationContext
  Public Sub New()
    Me.syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
  End Sub
  ''' <summary>
  ''' Установка контекста синхронизации.
  ''' </summary>
  ''' <param name="SynchronizationContext">Заданный контекст синхронизации.</param>
  Public Sub SetSynchronizationContext(SynchronizationContext As SynchronizationContext)
    Try
      Me.syncContext = SynchronizationContext
    Catch ex As Exception
      Me.syncContext = Nothing
      Exit Sub
    End Try
  End Sub
  Protected Overrides Sub OnCurrentChanged(e As EventArgs)
    If Me.syncContext IsNot Nothing Then
      Me.syncContext.Send(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf MyBase.OnCurrentChanged), e)
    Else
      MyBase.OnCurrentChanged(e)
    End If
  End Sub
  Protected Overrides Sub OnCurrentItemChanged(e As EventArgs)
    If Me.syncContext IsNot Nothing Then
      Me.syncContext.Send(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf MyBase.OnCurrentItemChanged), e)
    Else
      MyBase.OnCurrentItemChanged(e)
    End If
  End Sub
  Protected Overrides Sub OnPositionChanged(e As EventArgs)
    If Me.syncContext IsNot Nothing Then
      Me.syncContext.Send(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf MyBase.OnPositionChanged), e)
    Else
      MyBase.OnPositionChanged(e)
    End If
  End Sub
  Public Overloads Sub MoveNext()
    If Me.syncContext IsNot Nothing Then
      Me.syncContext.Send(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf MyBase.MoveNext), Nothing)
    Else
      MyBase.MoveNext()
    End If
  End Sub
  Public Overloads Sub MovePrevious()
    If Me.syncContext IsNot Nothing Then
      Me.syncContext.Send(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf MyBase.MovePrevious), Nothing)
    Else
      MyBase.MovePrevious()
    End If
  End Sub
  Public Overloads Sub MoveFirst()
    If Me.syncContext IsNot Nothing Then
      Me.syncContext.Send(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf MyBase.MoveFirst), Nothing)
    Else
      MyBase.MoveFirst()
    End If
  End Sub
  Public Overloads Sub MoveLast()
    If Me.syncContext IsNot Nothing Then
      Me.syncContext.Send(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf MyBase.MoveLast), Nothing)
    Else
      MyBase.MoveLast()
    End If
  End Sub
  Protected Overrides Sub OnListChanged(e As ListChangedEventArgs)
    If Me.syncContext IsNot Nothing Then
      Me.syncContext.Send(New SendOrPostCallback(AddressOf MyBase.OnListChanged), e)
    Else
      MyBase.OnListChanged(e)
    End If
  End Sub
End Class
```